# sqlite global variable bug

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I have a global variable named `mob`. When I print it the first time it is what I expect: 'Wolf'. But when I print it again in the end of `main`, it looks like 'до'. I debugged this code a lot and `mob` is global so I don't understand how it could be changed. I can add comments to part of the code if necessary.

I'm using sqlite3, Visual Studio 2010 and Win 7 x64.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "sqlite3.h"
struct Mob {
    Mob():_name(0),_lvl(0),_loot(0){}

unsigned const char* _name;
unsigned const char* _lvl;
unsigned const char* _loot;

}mob;

void main()
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt * pStmt;
    int i, j, coln, rc;
    int b = 1;

    char *sql[] = {
    "CREATE TABLE tbl (name TEXT,lvl INTEGER,loot TEXT);",
    "INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('Wolf',5,'Meat');",
    "SELECT * FROM tbl;"
    };  

    if (sqlite3_open("exam2.db", &db))
    {
        printf("Error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i=0; i<sizeof(sql)/sizeof(sql[0]); i++)
    {

        if (sqlite3_prepare(db, sql[i], -1, &pStmt, NULL))
        {
            printf("Error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);
            sqlite3_close(db);
            system("pause");
            exit(1);
        }

        coln = sqlite3_column_count(pStmt);


        while((rc = sqlite3_step(pStmt)) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            coln = sqlite3_data_count(pStmt);

            mob._name=sqlite3_column_text(pStmt, 0);
            std::cout<<mob._name<<std::endl; //1

        }

        if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)  printf("Error: %s\n", 
                sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);
    }


    std::cout<<mob._name<<std::endl; //2

    sqlite3_close(db);
    system("pause");
} //end main
```

Comment: By the way, "global" is the definition of "Bad, because it can be changed from anywhere".

Comment: You can read more on why [globals are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) on Wiki Wiki Web. When it comes to posting code, see [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) (thought the posted sample looks fairly minimal).

Comment: @outis I know that, this is just a test program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Mob::_name` is a raw pointer and you set it to a string that is owned and managed by SQLite. When you try to output the string again SQLite has already reused that memory, so your program runs into undefined behavior and you see garbage printed.

You should deep-copy the string - preferably by using `std::string` to store it.